# Flexbox stretch and vertically center multiline text in Zurb Foundation

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, flexbox

In a Zurb foundation project I am using Flexbox in a menu to allow for adding and removing of menu items that will adjust automatically. On large screens this appears to work perfectly, but one of the required menu items is a bit long and on resize for medium screens it breaks to a second line. This causes the menu to become huge. When I change the line height, it makes the hover action too small and aligns along the top. since I am using stretch in a row, I just cannot seem to get this to work correctly.

How can I get the menu to stay at the right height when the long menu item breaks to two lines while achieving the hover effect?

```
<div class="sticky">
  <nav class="top-bar hide-for-small" data-topbar role="navigation">
    <ul class="title-area">
      <li class="name"></li>

      <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span></span></a></li>
    </ul>

    <section class="top-bar-section">
      <ul class="full-width">
        <li id="top-bar-logo" style="display:none;"><a href="#"><img src="img/iowa-sm-mono.png"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Member Benefits</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="farmer-resources">Farmer Resources</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>

  </nav>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.top-bar-section > ul {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-flexbox;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

}

.top-bar-section > ul > li {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-flexbox;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -moz-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-direction: row;

}



.top-bar-section li:not(.has-form) a:not(.button) {
    color:#d1d1d1;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 1em;
    background: transparent;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: stretch;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.top-bar-section li:not(.has-form) a:not(.button):hover {
    background: #1fa67a;
}
```

See pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPxvLL

Answer (score 0):

one solution would be to add `white-space: nowrap;`to your css so that the text does not wrap into two lines.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogGVLQ